# AHK capture key combination left mouse button with other key

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys, mouse-buttons

I want to capture the hotkey combination left mouse button together with the key w.
Currently I have tried with no success:

```
Lbutton & w::doStuff()
*Lbutton & w::IfGetKeyState("w", P") doStuff()
```

Does anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When defining [custom combinations](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo), the first key (in this case the Lbutton) becomes the prefix key and loses its original function.

To avoid this in this case, make use of  the **[tilde prefix](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Tilde)** (~). It prevents AHK from blocking the key-down/up events.

```
~Lbutton & w:: doStuff()
```